# Скрытие текста в форме по клику

Tags: jquery

```css
label {
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
}

#LABEL_16 {
top: 25px;
```

```html
<input type="text" name="phone" id="INPUT_15" />
            <label for="modal_phone" >
              Телефон <span>*</span>
            </label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="INPUT_15" />
            <label  for="modal_phone" id="LABEL_16">
              Телефон <span>*</span>
            </label>
```

Как сделать что бы при клике по полю label скрывался. А если кликнуть на следующий инпут то в предыдущем label должен появится если текст не был введет. Так же должно происходить при клике вне инпута( label появляется если нет значений)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 1em;
}

.form-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-item input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.form-item label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.form-item label>span {
  color: #f00;
}

.form-item input:valid+label,
.form-item input:focus+label {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-item">
  <input type="tel" id="phone" required>
  <label for="phone">Телефон <span>*</span></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Внутри **input** добавить ***placeholder="Ваш текст внутри поле ввода"***

вот пример:

```html
<input type="text" name="phone" id="INPUT_15" placeholder="Введите ваш номер" />
```

При клике текст будет оставаться но при вводе текста, он уйдет.

Comment: текст в label нужен для стилизации. В placeholder этого нет